# selenium2 grid: scheduling job to run daily?

Tags: selenium, cron

In selenium2 grid, how would you set up specific tests to run daily? Basically something like a cron job to ensure it runs every interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use any type of scheduling or CI tool like

1. Hudson
2. Quartz
3. Cron job

to run the tests daily. Depending upon the size of your test you can decide which tool you would like to use

Comment: using RemoteWebDriver....how would you schedule it in cron which runs on the remote server?

Comment: How are you invoking your tests now?

Comment: basically I write a test in Java and connect to the remotewebdriver running on the remote server. I think Quartz Scheduler is suitable.